# SSIS-Export scripts from all the SQL Tasks to one file

Tags: c#, ssis

I have very big SSIS processes that contain a lot of SQL Script Tasks.
I want to export the content of  all the SQL Script Tasks  to one file
by c# code.
I looked for code but I didn't find.

Comment: Open up the file with a text reader and get it out of the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to KeithL's comment:
You can open the file with the .dtsx extension of the project
And take all the elements named `SQLTask: SQLTaskData` The statment is in the attribute `SQLTask: SQLStatmentTask`